Anyone know how to import an image from a SharePoint folder into an excel file (specific cell)?
Will continuously be updating image folder in SharePoint and need those images to update automatically in the excel file I have. Ideally, I need the images to land on a few specific cells but as long as it's within the same sheet.
I tried using the =image function but that only works with public URLs.

There is a solution suggested but not sure how reliable it is.
It works only occasionally on my site but that could be due to admin-enforced restrictions in my enterprise environment.
If you go to the end of your URL of the share link, you have a Question Mark (?) followed by letters (it's different for each URL). Replace the information after the question mark with download=1.
A detailed explanation is given in How to use the IMAGE function with SharePoint URLs
